# "An enigma is who I am"

Tags: riddle

> An enigma is who I am
>   I try to put people in a jam
>   My plans are not light, they're dark
>   I'm commonly seen with a question mark
>   And I do all this to foil the plan
>   Of one well-known certain man.

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> The Riddler

An enigma is who I am

> Edward Nygma, or E. Nygma, is the Riddler's real name

I try to put people in a jam

My plans are not light, they're dark

> He's a villain

I'm commonly seen with a question mark

> His costume features a question mark motif

And I do all this to foil the plan

Of one well-known certain man.

> Batman!

Comment: You got it! I'll accept the answer now.